# Postfix - How to configure to send these emails?

Tags: email, postfix

I want my mailserver to send mail from my local application "from" any user supplied email address "to" my own address, say "contact@mysite.com". The MX records for "mysite.com" actually point to a different server, even though the outgoing mainserver is running with mydomain set as "mysite.com". Perhaps this is part of the problem?

postfix is currently causing a SMTPRecipientsRefused error within the python application. Can anyone point me to what to change in the configuration?

Thanks

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = mysite.com, localhost.com, , localhost, *
myhostname = mysite.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: You might need to add the output of `postconf -n` to your question.  The `mynetworks` setting is the one I suspect isn't right.

Answer (score 2):

Your current `mynetworks` only allows the local machine to relay email.  It doesn't allow any other machines on the network to send emails (although it will still accept emails that it can deliver locally).

If your web box is not the same machine as your mail box, you will need to add your local network or the specific boxes to `mynetworks`.

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.0.0/24
```

or

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 10.0.0.0/8
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You have set

> mydestination = mysite.com,

So server tries to deliver it locally and probably recipient does not exist there.